# Cast simple object to simple and generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters, casting

I'm looking for a way to cast an object into a simple interface and to a generic interface which derives from the simple one.

Here is my example:

```
interface INonGeneric
{

}

interface IGeneric<T> : INonGeneric where T : ITypeParameter
{
    T Build();
}

interface ITypeParameter
{

}

class TypeClass : ITypeParameter
{

}
```

So this is the design I try to work with. If my understanding of generics is flawed, which I suppose it is, the mistake will hopefully be obvious for you.

Then I create the classes I want to use:

```
class MyClass : MyClassBase<TypeClass>
{
    public override TypeClass Build()
    {
        return new TypeClass();
    }
}

abstract class MyClassBase<T> : IGeneric<T> where T : ITypeParameter
{
    public abstract T Build();
}
```

And then I try to cast them like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    var cast1 = myClass as INonGeneric;
    if(cast1 != null) Console.WriteLine("cast 1 works!"); //THIS WORKS
    var cast2 = TestCast<ITypeParameter>(myClass);
    if(cast2 != null) Console.WriteLine("cast 2 works!"); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: sorry, I forgot to put in the TestCast Method. Here it is:

```
IGeneric<T> TestCast<T>(INonGeneric obj) where T : ITypeParameter
{
    return obj as IGeneric<T>;
}
```

Comment: I see, so this must mean, that I need to change it to this: 

    class MyClass : MyClassBase<ITypeParameter>
    {
        public override ITypeParameter Build()
 {
            return new TypeClass();
        }
    }

Comment: Take a look at [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). If you change you interface definition to `interface IGeneric<out T>`, then you'll be able to use the desired cast.

Comment: Yes, the `out` keyword in generics allows compiler to know that the type T in the interface is covariant (after that it'll be possible to make a conversion like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because of Covariance concern.
Consider this sample code.

```
var liInt = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};
var liObj = List<object>(liInt);
```

After that, you can seriously add some non-integer value to liObj and obviously, this is not OK.

```
bool b = false;
liObj.Add(b);
```

To preventing this you should tell implicitly that you use your generic type only in return places, not in inputs. For example:

```
interface IGeneric<out T> : INonGeneric where T : ITypeParameter
```

For more information please see link below:
http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem better now.
Also thanks to the other commenters.
I now managed to have a somewhat solid basis for my use.